# How to show linear independence of the vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let us say we have the following set of vectors: ${(1,-1,2),(2,0,1),(-1,2,-1)}$. We have to check for linear dependency. Now I know that we can do following: $$a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3=0$$ Now iff $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$, the vectors are linearly independant. But it seems I have to manually check for the coefficients, even if they are linearly dependant, let alone rule it out. Is there some other way around to check for the same?

Comment: put them in a matrix; they're dependent iff its determinant is $0$